# unittest- TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am running all test from class `TestNothing` using `unittest.TestSuite()`.

My `__init__.py` is:

```
import unittest
from .test_nothing import TestNothing


def suite():
    """
    Define suite
    """
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    test_suite.addTests([
        unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestNothing),
    ])
    return test_suite


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())
```

My `test_nothing.py` is:

```
import unittest


class TestNothing:
    def test_0010_test_nothing(self):
        self.assertEqual(200, 200)


def suite():
    "Test suite"
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    test_suite.addTests(
        unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestNothing)
    )
    return test_suite


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())
```

I am getting following error while running `python test_nothong.py` is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_nothing.py", line 19, in <module>
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())
  File "test_nothing.py", line 13, in suite
    unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestNothing)
  File 

"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 56, in loadTestsFromTestCase
        loaded_suite = self.suiteClass(map(testCaseClass, testCaseNames))
    TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

Comment: See the [Basic Example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example) in the docs. Your test class should derive from [**`unittest.TestCase`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, actually the constructor of TestNothing doesnt take argument...And it must.
I would suggest you to make your test class TestNothing inheriting from unittest.TestCase. like so, the Ctor of your class will inherit from the constuctor unittest.TestCase which take arguments.

```
import unittest
class TestNothing(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_0010_test_nothing(self):
        self.assertEqual(200, 200)
```

you can also go further, following this link [python unittest 25.3.1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html)